# How to get ortools to return cost?

Tags: or-tools

How does one get googleortools to give back the actual cost of a vrp? This example only returns distance and loads but if I add more cost elements I would like it to show me cheapest outcome. https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve it using `assignment.ObjectiveValue()` (in Python)

ps: on master all VRP samples should have the objective cost in the print function ;)